# Gnome-do crash at startup at Freya

Tags: applications, gtk

In Luna I used gnome-do without any issues (gnome-do is great btw).
In Freya I get:

`$ gnome-do
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(Do:10915): Wnck-CRITICAL **: wnck_set_client_type got called multiple times.

Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
Stacktrace:

at  <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Clipboard.gtk_clipboard_wait_is_text_available (intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at Gtk.Clipboard.WaitIsTextAvailable () <0x00017>
  at Do.Universe.SelectedTextItem.UpdateSelection (object,System.EventArgs) <0x00033>
  at Do.Platform.AbstractApplicationService.OnSummoned () <0x0002d>
  at Do.Platform.ApplicationService.m__0 (object,System.EventArgs) <0x00013>
  at Do.Core.Controller.OnSummoned () <0x0002d>
  at Do.Core.Controller.Summon () <0x00023>
  at Do.Do.Main (string[]) <0x001e3>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

```
/usr/bin/cli() [0x4b73d8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7f15cd46d340]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x39) [0x7f15cd0cecc9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f15cd0d20d8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x1b1a8) [0x7f15c951b1a8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_clipboard_wait_for_contents+0x6a) [0x7f15c089085a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_clipboard_wait_is_text_available+0x22) [0x7f15c0890cd2]
[0x4198143b]
```

Debug info from gdb:

Could not locate Tomboy on D-Bus. Perhaps it's not running?
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No threads.

=================================================================

Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.

=================================================================

Aborted (core dumped)`

I read some posts saying it was fixed, others saying that support for gtk2 applications is incomplete. Is there any way to use gnome-do?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible this is an old Gtk2 application levering some method it shouldn't be, and doesn't allow for third-party file choosers. elementary ships 3.14.15 on my system, with 2.24.23 as a fallback.

Comment: Any possible solutions? I think that installing gtk2 will break my system, I read that somewhere...

Comment: Have you tried Synapse instead?

Comment: It does the trick, but it does not solve the gnome-do problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in GNOME Do and would have to be corrected in Do's source code. See [this issue in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/1376530).

Since GNOME Do is no longer developed, it will likely never be fixed.

Comment: Its a shame such nice project was dropped.